# Laravel migrations created the wrong datatype in mysql DB. Works as expected in local environment

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

Laravel 9 / PHP 8.1 / MySQL Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.38, for Linux (x86_64)

Our Ticketsystems Database was changed manually a few times without migrations so I adapted all migrations, took a backup, tried it locally and then did the same with the live DB.

The content of tickets is saved in the description field, which was originally a string. It was changed manually in the database to longtext. I have now changed the migration to longText as well, which creates it as longText on my local machine.

```
$table->longText('description')->nullable();
```

However it still creates it as varchar(255) on the live system and I have no idea why or where to start looking for a reason. I'd rather not screw around with changing the DB manually again.

Answer (score 0):

Why use LONGTEXT for a description, you can use TEXT type.

> TEXT has a maximum length of 64 kilobytes—the same as VARCHAR.
>
> MEDIUMTEXT has a maximum length of about 16 megabytes.
>
> LONGTEXT has a maximum length of about **4 gigabytes**.

I dont think you want to save 4GB of description in text.

So yeah, the method `text()` exists in the migration schema methods (as longText() and mediumText()).

```
$table->text('description')->nullable();
```

I dont know why your getting a varchar(255), maybe it is not the right migration that you modified or you have something in your application boot that forces it.

Comment: Some descriptions are already too long for text() unfortunately. Changing it with another migration and doctrine/dbal results in an error.

Comment: @j-bill how many characters your longest description is ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe in this case you should try to follow this approach:
Install `composer require doctrine/dbal` and then change your migration to

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->text('description')->change();
    });
}
```

Comment: I've tried that aswell last week. It had no effect on the database unfortunately. I left the migration there, added a comment and then changed it manually.